# Crack detection opencv c++

Tags: image, opencv, c++11, detection

I am new to image processsing i want to detect crack please any one can help me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n5Yj.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description that you're presenting, I believe that the best way to do this is by using a binary mask with the `cv2.binary_and()` function.

You can do this color segmentation by using 2 thresholds that are going to be the minimum and the maximum color values for the color of the cracks.

Another sollution may be the usage of the Otsu's threshold method. This probably will generate the best values for your mask.

After the masking of the image, you'll have to try to create the contours of those cracks in the image. You can use the `cv2.findContours()` function. (Check this link that describes the way you can [implement this function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html))